# Change parent of commit without doing git rebase

Tags: git

I need to shrink my long living GIT repository by removing old commits history.

Transform sth like this:

```
A - B - D - E - ... 
 \ /         
  C
```

Into:

```
       D' - E - ...
```

the commits history after commit E is quite complex, contains a lot of branches, tags, merges etc.

I don't care about other users because this is a migrated repo that has not yet been pushed to any remote repository. It is a bare repository on my local machine. I can transform it to a "normal" one if needed.

To create D' and print its hash I could use:

```
git commit-tree D^{tree}
```

But the question is how switch the parent of commit E from commit D to commit D'?

At this stage, most of the tips I've already found suggest doing a rebase master branch onto D', but it's not so easy when you have a complex history with commits for over a decade with a lot of multiple branches, tags, merges etc.

Is there any low-level GIT command to simply switch the pointer to the parent commit without doing a git rebase when I'm 100% sure that the new parent commit contains all content of the current one?

Comment: You _can't_ do this without a rebase and rewrite of the history.  Also, your before and after diagrams are not clear, and it isn't obvious what you really want here.

Comment: I simplified the diagram and changed the description a bit to make it easier to understand what I mean.

Comment: "*Is need to shrink my long living GIT repository...*" Why?

Comment: Note that using `git replace` followed by either `git filter-repo` (newfangled) or `git filter-branch` (the old method) will do the job (remember to delete the "replacement" commit when you're done, too, if the filter didn't). You're not actually *changing* the *existing* commits, though: instead, you're adding *new* commits, (very) roughly doubling the size of your repository in the process. You can shrink it back down afterward. Filter-repo appears to do the subsequent shrink for you, which makes it a lot more convenient.

Comment: @Schwern The repository after migration is too big to be uploaded to the GitLab.
GitLab has a repo size limit of 10GB.
To keep the full story, I have to cut it into several small repositories, containing history from different time periods.

Comment: @Gilmor Repos usually get that large because of very large files. Consider instead [migrating your repo to Git Large File Storage with the BFG Repo Cleaner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/migrate_to_git_lfs.html). Your repo size will shrink and you will retain full history.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `git filter-repo` ([project page](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)) :

> *excerpt from [the doc](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/7b3e714b94a6e5b9f478cb981c7f560ef3f36506/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt#L928)* :
> **Parent rewriting**
>
> To replace $commit_A with $commit_B (e.g. make all commits which had
> $commit_A as a parent instead have $commit_B for that parent), and
> rewrite history to make it permanent:
>
> ```
> git replace $commit_A $commit_B
> git filter-repo --force
> ```